Приходит html вместо json
Структура проекта

frontend

components

Employee.tsx
Employees.tsx


pages


{... и так далее}



backend

index.js
controllers

controller.js


routes

route.js


models

Employee.js


.env




Содержимое файлов:
//index.js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const employeeRoutes = require('./routes/route');

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
  .catch(err => console.error('Something went wrong', err));

app.use('/api', employeeRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

//controllers/controller.js
const Employee = require('../models/Employee');

const getAllEmployees = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const employees = await Employee.find();
    res.json(employees);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
module.exports = { getAllEmployees}

//routes/route.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { getAllEmployees, createEmployee } = require('../controllers/controller');

router.get('/getemployees', getAllEmployees);
//router.post('/addemployee', createEmployee);

module.exports = router;

//models/Employee.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {type: Number, required: true},
  firsName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  imageUrl: {type: String, required: true},
  phone: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  position: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  likes: { type: String, required: true },
});

const Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', employeeSchema);

module.exports = Employee;

//Employees.tsx
const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/getemployees');

Проблема:

Приходит HTML документ вместо json (из-за этого вот такая ошибка employees.map is not a function)
Еще есть вот такое
Could not load content for webpack:///react-devtools-shared/src/backend/console.js (Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)

Пожалуйста, помогите понять, что не так.

Какой конкретно HTML документ хоть? И с каким HTTP-кодом?

@andreymal
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fsfaInX-pG0pdIBQO_d1kItWTy5yR0uJ/view?usp=sharing
ответ - 200

Middleware по обработке ошибок, должна быть в самом конце. Принимать 4 параметра, первый из них это error и обязательно, чтобы была функция next в качестве последнего параметра.
